# "Commit failed - exit code 1 received" when trying to commit a new local reprository in gihub desktop

Tags: github, github-desktop

when I am trying to commit my new local repository at **GitHub** from **GitHub-desktop**  it is throwing an error **"Commit failed - exit code 1 received"**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Regarding:

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1711576/26461047/58a465c6-4184-11e7-9ed4-baac5cde302e.png]

Check first if you have added files to your index.
Open the command line and check your `git status`.

Second, see [desktop/desktop issue 3701](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3701#issuecomment-375905661):

> some users have run into this error due to having nested `.git` directories.
>   Can you try searching your repository to see if you have multiple `.git` directories?
>
> Had a `.git` in my repository (which I needed) and a `.git` in a subfolder (which I deleted), then it worked.

Finally, check if you have any submodule (a `.gitmodules` file at the root of your repo).
See [desktop/desktop issue 1770](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/1770).

> If I commit changes in submodule myself than GitHub Desktop is able to push and/or commit changes after that. After submodule is committed manually SHA1 changes from dirty. At this point I can commit to main repo.

Comment: I am using nuxt.js inside Django. As a result, there were two .git folders. One for Django and another for Nuxt.js. I deleted the one for Nuxt.js. Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I removed the repository from GitHub Desktop (not from the disk) and then added it again as a local repository and this solved the issue for me.

I was receiving this error as well, but unlike others I did not have have any nested .git folders. When trying to view changes, each of the files appeared as "empty" until I removed the repository from GitHub Desktop and added it again.

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same thing and it's caused by .git in subfolder.

Just removed all related .git files and the error disappeared.

Comment: That's right. I added another GitHub Repo to my own Repo. With Windows, the .git folder is normally invisible. You can see and delete him when you change the appearance of invisible folders.

Answer (score 1):

exitcode 1 while committing is not always a real "error".

i do not know GitHub-desktop (and which commands exactly be executed by GitHub-desktop) but maybe your problem has the same core-"problem" as my problem some days ago.
in my case i had a branch `master` which tracks/follows `origin/master`. i executed:

```
git pull --no-commit --no-ff
git commit -m "merge"
```

i found that if `origin/master` has no commits which can be pulled by the `git pull`-command then the `git commit`-command is obviously doing nothing because there are no staged changes and has (imo: surprisingly) the exit-code 1 although no error occurred.

(i guess git commit should have exitcode 0 if it has really created a commit).

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. 
I committed via cmd prompt and did not face this issue again.

Answer (score 0):

For the Github desktop,click on the plus sign on the left-hand side of your Github desktop and then select 'Discard .git' files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).