# Github desktop commit failed: Commit failed - exit code 1 received - 'file' does not have our version

Tags: swift, git, github, github-desktop

Here is the full error message `Commit failed - exit code 1 received, with output: 'error: path 'databaseProject/Services/WorkoutService.swift' does not have our version'`

I was trying to merge into origin, but after resolving all conflicts I was presented with this error, and cannot find any information on it.

Comment: Curious. I googled for "github Commit failed exit code 1 does not have our version" and the first hit links to https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3701#issuecomment-375905661. If not: that repo is _definitely_ the first place to ask, not Stackoverflow.

Comment: A more direct rewording of @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans comment : check if there is an existing folder named `databaseProject/.git`. If there is, this means `databaseProject` is a git repo itself, and the parent repo completely ignores the content in this subdirectory. Do you remember how you set up this `databaseProject` folder ?

Answer (score 1):

even though Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans should most likely be the reason anyway I'd like to add:
More reasons can already be found in ["Commit failed - exit code 1 received" when trying to commit a new local reprository in gihub desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50052115/commit-failed-exit-code-1-received-when-trying-to-commit-a-new-local-reprosi) (might even be a duplicate anyway).

In case you actually need nested Git repositories, you could use [Git Submodules.](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Cheers,
Dominic